# What can cause an intermitent ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error?

Tags: oracle, ora-12560

I have a poorly written legacy .NET application that is in constant contact with the database throwing up a "No Connection" screen if it detects that connectivity has been dropped.

All machines running this program are configured identically but on two of them we just recently started running into a problem where the No Connection screen comes up regardless of whether there is connectivity or not and won't detect the connection until the computer itself is restarted.

Looking into error logs it seems that the culprit is

```
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

But what can possibly be causing this?  Especially since this wasn't happening until just a few weeks ago.

Comment: Is the tnsnames on each machine or on a network drive?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, the machines cannot resolve the `DNS` names provided in the `HOST` entry of `tnsnames.ora`, or access the server provided in the `HOST` entry.

If the connection drops on timeout (as if underlying `TCP` stream drops on timeout), it will also fail with this message.

If you use `tnsnames.ora` on `Oracle 10g` or higher, try to use `Easy Connect` format (`//servername/servicename`) instead.

Comment: +1 for easy connect reference - kewl. It would be even nicer if it didn't require the password on the command line and prompted for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I this is what you get whenever something bad happens to the network.

A common special case of that are firewalls or other network gadgets that shutdown idle connections.

Comment: Hmm perhaps, but it can't re-open them even when I restart the application?

Answer (score 0):

On our C:\Oracle directory, some of the files were compressed (blue).  Once we uncompressed the files, our problem went away.

Comment: Blue? It's easy to set up different colours. (my zip files are green)

Comment: @Ben: LOL comment filler string! :D